# I can't get Cinnamon to stop freezing, how can I revert it back?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have an issue, and I'm unsure if it is a bug or not but here's the skinny:

I updated cinnamon from 1.6.7 to 1.8 (don't get me wrong, I love it BUT!)

Ever since I did the update, Cinnamon has been freezing on me. The mouse moves, but nothing is click-able (so I can't right click the panel > Troubleshoot > restart cinnamon).
*--My mindset for this is that the freezing can be tolerable if I can just restart cinnamon without having to continuously restart my computer about four to six times a day.*

I can be in Firefox mid-type, mid-scroll, trying to minimize (one time, froze while trying to maximize), and trying to move the window. I opened up Skype, went to login and it froze. Opened up the Menu and it froze. Right clicked the desktop, tried to pick an option and it froze.

I don't know if it is just me or not, but either way, there is a rather annoying issue on my hands. There were glitches in 1.6.7, but it never froze. *And I had the ability to right click the panel to restart Cinnamon to fix the issues then.*

**Details:**

Linux Mint 13 (cinnamon 1.8)
Processor: AMD Turion(tm) 64 X2 Mobile Technology TL-58 x 2
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on NV4E
OS type: 32 bit

**What I've Done So Far**

went into tty2 and typed in

```
export DISPLAY=:0; cinnamon --replace &
```

The first response I received was

```
[1] 2940
```

followed up by

```
Window manager error: Unable to open X display
```

(Got the idea from [Ubuntu SE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143838/how-do-i-restart-cinnamon-from-the-tty) and tried all the answers there too, nothing worked. The idea of just hitting 'r' and enter didn't help me restart cinnamon either.)

The last thing I did was completely removed Cinnamon and then reinstalled it:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cinnamon  
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

I restarted my computer, logged in, 5 minutes later, it froze. (:/ didn't help)

Since I don't think I can fix this, is there a way to "roll-back" to 1.6.7.?

Answer (score 3):

The following commands should do what you want:

```
sudo apt-get purge cinnamon
sudo apt-get install cinnamon=1.6.7
gsettings reset-recursively org.cinnamon
```

If you can't find the packages in your repository you can still download them manually here:

- http://packages.linuxmint.com/list.php?release=Debian

cinnamon 1.6.7+lmde:

- [amd64 (2.5 MB)](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/c/cinnamon/cinnamon_1.6.7+lmde_amd64.deb)
- [i386 (2.5 MB)](http://packages.linuxmint.com/pool/main/c/cinnamon/cinnamon_1.6.7+lmde_i386.deb)

Once you download which ever architecture you have you can install it like this:

```
dpkg -i <cinnamon.deb>
apt-get -fy install
```

The first command will install your download .deb file, the second will install any dependencies that it might require.

Comment: I thank you, and it was all fine and dandy until `version 1.6.7 for cinnamon was not found`... so I'm guessing it was taken down or something. But thank you anyway! +1 for the useful answer (in all seriousness, it would have reverted back if 1.6.7 was still there; can't fault you for that)

Comment: Well, I had a dumb moment. I was too busy being concerned that Cinnamon wasn't working right that I completely ignored the fact that the options you gave were for LMDE. I don't have LMDE. But either way, fixed my own issue without having to downgrade. And still, I thank you for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem with fresh install of Mint 15.

```
dmesg
```

shows nouveau error ("fail ttm_validate"). The problem got solved by installing the proprietary nVidia drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If this does not work for you, try

`sudo pkill -SIGHUP cinnamon`

instead of --replace. This will merely redraw all windows rather than killing them. But browser downloads tend to get prematurely terminated.